# grouping the list object with where clauses and return

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get the grouped list based on the where clause from the List. How I can do that.  Below is the example.

```
public class OrderUpdate
{

    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int OrderType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public string TrackingId { get; set; }

    public OrderUpdate GetGroupedList()
    {    
        var UpdateList = new List<OrderUpdate>();
        var groupedList = UpdateList.GroupBy(u => u.TrackingId);
        // where OrderType in (1, 2, 3, 4)  and add this in groupedlist 
        // which is objecct of OrderUpdate
        return groupedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: groupedlist is a property of OrderUpdate or method GetGroupedList return list of OrderUpdate ?

Comment: uh.. care to elaborate on *where OrderType in (1, 2, 3, 4)  and add this in groupedlist*, are you perhaps wish to group `OrderUpdate` by `TrackingId` that have `OrderType` in 1, 2, 3, 4? if its so, you could filter it first (do `Where`) and then group. ie. `int[] refOrderType = {1, 2, 3, 4}; UpdateList.Where(x => refOrderType.Contains(x.OrderType)).GroupBy(x => x.TrackingId);` -- you got the gist la, [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919695/c-sharp-linq-expression-in-lambda-with-contains).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't compile.  I assume you want to order the list by `TrackId` and filter on some order types.

```
public IEnumerable<OrderUpdate> GetList()
{
   var validOrderTypes = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
   var UpdateList = new List<OrderUpdate>();
   // TODO: fill the list

   return UpdateList
     .Where(u => validOrderTypes.Contains(u.OrderType))
     .OrderBy(u => u.TrackId);
}
```