# How to get all the titles matching at least one word in the titleNames in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have to get all the titles whose titleName matches at least one word in the "searchText" string using Entity Framework and Lamda expression. I am splitting the searchText when there is a space and storing the result in an array. I am writing the following code but unable to get the desired output.

```
var searchTextArray = searchText.Split(' ');
var result = entities.titles.Where(x => searchTextArray.Contains(x.titleName));
```

Suppose the searchText contains **"Loneliness Management"** string, then I want to get all the titles containing the titleName any of the words.
I this case I should get the titles whose titleNames as

```
Some loneliness affect all
Loneliness is painful
School Management
Proper management
```

...

**Update 1:**
The above query is generating the SQL as

```
SELECT * FROM titles  WHERE (LOWER(titleName) IN (N'loneliness', N'management')) AND (LOWER(titleName) IS NOT NULL)
```

But I want to generate the query like as

```
SELECT * FROM titles WHERE titleName like N'%loneliness%' or titleName like N'%management%'
```

What am I missing in the above expression?

**Update 2**

**I got the expected output from @3dGrabber answer but still the generated SQL Query is a bit messy than LIKE operator in T-SQL.** Thank you so much all. The generated SQL is now like as

```
SELECT 
    *
    FROM [dbo].[titles] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            N'loneliness' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            N'management' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]
        WHERE ( CAST(CHARINDEX([UnionAll1].[C1], LOWER([Extent1].[titleName])) AS int)) > 0
    )
```

Comment: In what way does the above not work for you?

Comment: This should work. Maybe you wanted to do case-insensitive search? You can apply `.ToLower()` to `searchText` and `x.titleName`

Comment: @SlavenTojić Why would adding `ToArray` make any difference at all?

Comment: Again, in what way does the above code not work for you? What output are you getting?

Comment: C# linq expression in lambda with contains, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919695/c-sharp-linq-expression-in-lambda-with-contains)

Comment: C# linq expression in lambda with contains, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919695/c-sharp-linq-expression-in-lambda-with-contains)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if EF can transpile all the operations used, but this is what I would do in Linq-to-Objects:

```
var searchText = "Loneliness Management";
var searchTerms = searchText.ToLower().Split(' ');

var entities = new [] 
{
    "Some loneliness affect all",
    "Loneliness is painful",
    "School Management",
    "No match here",
    "Maybe the next one?",
    "Proper management"
 };

var titles = entities.Select(t => t.ToLower());

var result = titles.Where(t => searchTerms.Any(s => t.Contains(s)));
```

If you want case-insensitive search, make sure EF supports it, or put the data lowercased into the DB in the first place. Otherwise you will probably run into performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to do a case-insensitive search. You can apply `.ToLower()` to `searchText` and `x.titleName`:

```
var searchTextArray = searchText.ToLower().Split(' ');
var result = entities.titles.Where(x => searchTextArray.Contains(x.titleName.ToLower()));
```

---

**UPDATE**

I can't think of a way to make the EF generate a query like this: `SELECT * FROM titles WHERE titleName like N'%loneliness%' or titleName like N'%management%'`.

I think your best bet is to use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build an expression, something like this:

```
var searchTextArray = searchText.Split(' ');

var baseExpression = PredicateBuilder.False<TEntity>(); // TEntity - typeof your entity
foreach(var sourceToken in searchTextArray)
{
    var temp = sourceToken;
    baseExpression = baseExpression.Or(x => x.Body.Contains(sourceToken));
}

var result = entities.titles.Where(baseExpression).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not 100% efficient but seems to be working.

```
var source = "test management".Split(" ");
var list = new List<string> { "hello world", "world management test" };
var result = list.Where(x => x.Split(" ").Intersect(source).Any());
```

Basically you split your string into a list of items and then do an intersection with your source and see if you find anything.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Question was regarding Entity Framework, while you build a list in memory. `x.Split(" ").Intersect(source).Any()` wouldn't work in a EF linq query.

Comment: i built the list to simulate an entity framework query...tbh if you query EF and to a tolist has the same result...give it a go, i did

Comment: Sorry, but this code wouldn't work. Even the `.Split()` call is invalid, as there are no overload which accepts string ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)).